# Querying dynamic JSON fields for first non-null value in AWS Athena

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I am storing event data in S3 and want to use Athena to query the data. One of the fields is a dynamic JSON field that I do not know the field names for. Therefore, I need to query the keys in the JSON and then use those keys to query for the first non-null for that field. Below is an example of the data stored in S3.

```
{
 timestamp: 1558475434,
 request_id: "83e21b28-7c12-11e9-8f9e-2a86e4085a59",
 user_id: "example_user_id_1",
 traits: {
  this: "is",
  dynamic: "json",
  as: ["defined","by","the", "client"]
 }
}
```

So, I need a query to extract the keys from the traits column (which is stored as JSON), and use those keys to get the first non-null value for each field.

The closest I could come was sampling a value using min_by, but this does not allow for me to add a where clause without returning null values. I will need to use presto's "first_value" option, but I cannot get this to work with the extracted JSON keys from the dynamic JSON field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT trait, min_by(json_extract(traits, concat('$.', cast(trait AS varchar))), received_at) AS value
FROM TABLE
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(regexp_extract_all(traits,'"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*("[^"]+"|[^,{}]+)', 1)) AS t(trait)
WHERE json_extract(traits, concat('$.', cast(trait AS varchar))) IS NOT NULL OR json_size(traits, concat('$.', cast(trait AS varchar))) <> 0
GROUP BY  trait
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect as result? "The first non-null value for each field" is not entirely clear, the values are both strings and arrays, and none in the example are null. Do you mean that when a value is an array to get the first non-null element or just to get the non-null values regardless of type?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you expect as result, and what you mean by "first non-null value". In your example you have both string and array values, and none of them is null. It would be helpful if you provided more examples and also expected output.

As a first step towards a solution, here's a way to filter out the null values from `traits`:

If you set the type of the `traits` column to `map<string,string>` you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT
  request_id,
  MAP_AGG(ARRAY_AGG(trait_key), ARRAY_AGG(trait_value)) AS trait
FROM (
  SELECT
    request_id,
    trait_key,
    trait_value
  FROM some_table CROSS JOIN UNNEST (trait) AS t (trait_key, trait_value)
  WHERE trait_value IS NOT NULL
)
```

However, if you want to also filter values that are arrays and pick out the first non-null value, that becomes more complex. It could probably be done with a combination of casts to JSON, the `filter` function, and `COALESCE`.